# What is the definition of $(dx)?$

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, infinitesimals

I often see in calculus that we treat the symbols $dx$ and $dy$ as infinitesimal numbers but I don't really accept this definition because in the real number line there's no such thing as infinitesimals.

I read in [Calculus by Michael Spivak](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Calculus/7JKVu_9InRUC?hl=en&gbpv=0&kptab=overview) that the $dx$ [has no meaning](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=7JKVu_9InRUC&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=spivak%20The%20symbol%20dx%20has%20no%20meaning%20in%20isolation,%20any%20more%20that%20the%20symbol&source=bl&ots=wmMGJgDYQd&sig=ACfU3U1TsTbGcJdiTe7mqp93CpF8TpUeFw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdn8Cl6Ob3AhUjRmwGHXexC8sQ6AF6BAgYEAM#v=onepage&q=spivak%20The%20symbol%20dx%20has%20no%20meaning%20in%20isolation%2C%20any%20more%20that%20the%20symbol&f=false) [Page $264$].

> **Image**
> [image: Textbook Snapshot]
>
> **In [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)**
> The symbol $dx$ has no meaning in isolation, any more that the symbol $x \rightarrow$ has any meaning, except in the context $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x).$

So Can someone explain it in explicit way and the true definition for it ?

Comment: The elementary view is that it's just an element of syntax that doesn't mean anything outside of derivatives and integrals. There's a less elementary view in terms of differential forms but it's not really philosophically distinct from this "element of syntax" view. There are also a few different systems of "nonstandard analysis" which give a rigorous treatment of infinitesimals. Overall as a beginner to the subject I would not suggest you look into either of these topics.

Comment: @Ian but we mean in derivative and integral by (dx) we mean We differentiate w.r.t x or we integrate w.r.t x , and also in spivak's Calculus we clarified in the derivative chapter that the (dy) and (dx) are not infinetismals and they aren't numbers and when we write dy/dx this doesn't mean a qouteint ,is this the elementary view that you were referring to??

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It's just part of how we write down derivatives and integrals and that's really it.

Comment: @user1046533 
I just want to be sure that it's rigor definition is not infinetismals because as I said there is not such thing called infinetismals  in real number line

Comment: I fall into the category of people that strongly dislike the appeals to differential geometry. It's simply very clever notation that mimics delta notation in Riemann sums and works extremely well with chain rule for substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

the exact definition is this:

> if $\mathbf{x}$ denotes the general point of $\mathbb{R^n}$, we denote
> the $i^{th}$ projection function mapping $\mathbb{R^n}$ to
> $\mathbb{R}$ by the symbol $x_i$. Then $dx_i$ equals the elementary
> 1-form $\tilde{\phi_i}$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: well in fact I don't really know what you've written (I suspect it's diffrential geometry but i don't have any background on diffrential geometry ) what I want to be sure of that in standard analysis the infinetismals don't really exist

Comment: @Abdelrahman Perhaps you could make your question clearer by specifying the type of answer that you're looking for.  As written, this does seem to provide an answer to your question.

Comment: @Abdelrahman It does not depend it is analysis or geometry, it's same every where in pure mathematics. the fact is you need quite bit of readings in analysis to understand this notation, specifically you need to be familiar with differential forms. I strongly recommend Analysis on manifolds by munkres.

Comment: @DavoodKarimi 
Does the definition you provided differs from the definition in Michael spivak book?

Comment: @Abdelrahman if you refer to the image you've posted, that's not a definition.

Comment: @DavoodKarimi 
No I don't refer to image but in this chapter, he wrote that we can replace (dx) and we mean by it (for all x)

Answer (score 0):

Let a differentiable real function $f:U\subset \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, a $x\in U$ and a real number $Δx$. We define the differential of $f$ as the real function of two real variables $df$ via $df(x,Δx):=f'(x)Δx$. If $f$ is the identity map$f(x)=id(x)=x$, $x\in U$, then $df(x,Δx)=dx(x,Δx)=(x)'Δx=Δx$, so $dx=Δx$, thus $dx$ means the differential of the identity map. (It is useful a geometric approach by plotting a graph of an arbitrary differentiable function.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a page off of actual differential geometry here because in one dimension it's actually pretty easy.

Consider the set of all smooth (or even differentiable) functions $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. Call this set $C$. Then at every point $p\in \Bbb{R}$ we can define the following operator:
$$\frac{d}{dx}|_p : C \to \Bbb{R}$$
And it is defined by:
$$\frac{d}{dx}|_p(f) = f'(p)$$
This operator is linear, in the sense that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}|_p(\alpha f + \beta g) = \alpha \frac{d}{dx}|_p (f) + \beta \frac{d}{dx}|_p (g)$$
where $\alpha, \beta$ are real numbers and $f, g \in C$.\
We are interested in operators with these properties because they have amazing algebraic properties and structure.

Now let us define another operator $df$, this time it takes an operator of the kind discussed above and it feeds a pre-determined function $f \in C$ to it.
$$ df(\frac{d}{dx}|_p) = f'(p)$$
This might look like fancy notation for the same thing as before, but as a matter of fact this allows you to "fix the derivative and choose the function to derive". So for example $dg$ will take a derivative and apply it to $g$. This operator is also linear in the sense that:
$$df(\alpha \frac{d}{dx}|_p) = \alpha df(\frac{d}{dx}|_p)$$
with $\alpha$ real number.

In particular, $dx$ applies the operator to the function $x$, which is the identity function, and evaluates it at $p$. So $dx$, as a function of operators, is the function such that $dx(\frac{d}{dx}|_p) = 1$ for all $p$.

This has nothing to do with infinitesimals, and in fact the relationship between this definition of $dx$ and the integral is more convoluted than just assuming $dx$ to mean tiny steps.\
To conclude, in standard analysis (and differential geometry) infinitesimals do not exist in the sense of tiny steps.

For those who know what I'm talking about already: I know I'm being sloppy, but I think it's best to give an intuitive idea of what is going on.